# How to plot latitude and longitude stored in database on ArcGIS map

Tags: jquery, arcgis-platform, asp.net

I am **new** to ArcGIS and I have tried basic things like I created a **csv** file with **latitude,longitude and place** as data in it.
I **imported** that file as a **layer** when I created a **web map** in ArcGIS.

This showed me all the places and plotted it on my map. It shows something like this.

[image]

I am building a website using **asp.net MVC** and **jQuery** which will show a map on page, and I want to show data something like in the image on my web page.

What I have to do is to link my database to this map. That is, when the table in database gets new values it should automatically plot it on the map.
I also know about **services** provided by ArcGIS.

Can I **use** those services and **pass** my **data** to them through **jQuery**? If yes, can you please let me know how to do it?

I researched a lot on how to pass my data to map but I couldn't find any solution. But I found some topics which I thought would be required to make it happen.

Topics like **ArcGIS web servers for services** which is server for services.
But to host a service I will have to create a service and I couldn't find any topic on **how to create your own service**.

I also found out that there is **ArcGIS for desktop**. Do I have to install it to create services?

I think I am going in a wrong direction. Can you guys please help me with right direction.

Comment: Please do not bold every other word in your question.  This greatly reduces the readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well quite a broad question(s). I will just try to explain in simple words how it works and try to not slip into too much detail to confuse you.

As I am deducing from opening of your question, you have used ArcGIS online to create your points and map. This is cloud-based solution. For now there is no need to explain what is cost to use it, It just can be used for building some applications and publishing some types of map services. Your concern is I assume so called Feature service, which store your points and can be edited. You have to figure out yourself how (you probably did it) how to publish your points as a Feature service in this ArcGIS online, but the point is that it is rest web services that interacts with your data. I will come back to it in a while.

If you are not interest in cloud solution and you have your own map server,  in this case ArcGIS Server, you can publish various types of map services from your data. For publication of these services you need ArcGIS desktop, to design how your data should be represented and many other things…  Just because you asked for it, here is some documentation about how to publish your services: http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/how-to-publish-a-service.htm. The point is that your services are again the same type of rest service as in previous paragraph. So you have your spatial data accessible by rest endpoint and you can play with your data and make map applications.

For making use of these map services esri provides javascript-based framework, which is nicely documented and sampled here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/. I recommend you to have a look here. The other thing is that this framework is built in dojo and to use all its functionality you need to use dojo. (I am using this framework with asp.net MVC and so far all goes well).

As already few times mentioned, you are interacting with data by rest services, so in some cases you just need to make correct http request to manipulate or get your data. For this purpose have a look here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html. And for this purpose I think you can do it just by jQuery.

There are other frameworks like Leaflet or OpenLayers and I think there are ways how to use these ArcGIS services( they are proprietary, not standardized by default) with these frameworks. It just may be more complicated.

Just read some stuff in those links I provided and I think you will see, how to proceed. At the end it always depends on your needs…

Comment: thanks for the answer... I will search and read more on the topics you shared.

Comment: hello makak, I tried to search on how to create a ArcGIS server.. I couldn't find anything. Can you please share link where I can find steps to create Server?

Comment: ArcGIS Server is a software (quite expensive), you have to buy it and then install it. There are open source alternatives of course, like Geoserver, Mapserver and probably others...